# Getting low quality images in corel 14

Tags: adobe-photoshop, coreldraw

I am a kids book designer, I am using Corel 14.

I want to use Photoshop CS5 for designing instead Corel. But I want the final product in Corel.

The question is when I import JPEG made from Photoshop in Corel the high quality JPEG from Photoshop shows poor quality in Corel

It results in zigzag edges in Corel.

Can anyone answer what is the missing step or what is the step should I take for good quality in Corel.

Comment: A word of advice, JPEG is a *lossy* image type (i.e. you will lose information and, depending on your quality settings, you might end up with blurred/pixelated spots all over the image). Try to save in a *lossless* format like PNG and see if it works.

Comment: Any particular reason you want the final product to be Corel?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your screen quality in Corel is set to 'concept' or 'normal' - should be set to 'high quality'. This only gives the APPEARANCE of a low res image.
Check the resolution of the image by clicking on it and reading the resolution below in the status bar. If it's too low, it could also be that you've scaled the image to a bigger format in Corel.

---

Another possibility is that you've given the jpeg in Photoshop a lower resolution than the original image e.g. when saving it for web and devices.

---

The best way to transport an image is to save it as tiff because of the lossy nature of jpg, see also comments section.
Watch closely that you do not do unnecessary profile conversions and the output resolution is the same as the original image resolution.
succes!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the imported image to Coreldraw's bitmap. Use 300dpi and CMYK.

Use enhanced view and press F9 to see a better quality preview of your process.